# jquery - nav home image fades in on mouseout between hovering over every nav image

Tags: jquery, mouseover, fadein, fadeout, nav

If for instance I hover over the contact_text image and then the about_text image, rather than the contact_text image fading out and the about_text image fading in instantly, the home_text image fades in briefly between them. Please help. Thanks

Note - I'm using the .rollover class on the image for an image rollover effect. It's probably not relevant to my issue.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<a href="#"><img src="images/nav/home_hover.png" id="home"></a>

<a href="#"><img src="images/nav/portfolio.png" alt="images/nav/portfolio_hover.png" class="rollover" id="portfolio"></a>

<a href="#"><img src="images/nav/about.png" alt="images/nav/about_hover.png" class="rollover" id="about"></a>

<a href="#"><img src="images/nav/contact.png" alt="images/nav/contact_hover.png" class="rollover" id="contact"></a>

</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.rollover').rollover();
  });

  $("#portfolio").mouseover(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#portfolioText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home.png");
});
 $("#portfolio").mouseout(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#portfolioText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home_hover.png");
});

$("#about").mouseover(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#aboutText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home.png");
});
 $("#about").mouseout(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#aboutText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home_hover.png");
});

$("#contact").mouseover(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#contactText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home.png");
});
 $("#contact").mouseout(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeIn("fast");
    $("#contactText").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#home").attr("src","images/nav/home_hover.png");
});
</script>
```